# How to import Text Fairy OCR demo application in android studio?

Tags: android, ocr

I have downloaded Text Fairy OCR source code from https://github.com/renard314/textfairy but there are two other library project are not available 1.ViewPager3D  and 2. tess-two. so i have separately downloaded. This two project are not gradle based project. I tried to integrate it but getting many errors. Please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your integration doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: hey @4Droid how can you solve that problem?